# Xcode can't restore snapshot

Tags: xcode, snapshot

I'm using Xcode 6.2 and I'm trying to restore a snapshot.  When I try I get a window where the left side is a long list of files from lots of different projects, on the right is an empty window that says "File does not exist in restore location".  I'm not sure what's going on.  I read that deleted files might cause snapshot restore to have a problem.  I went through my files in Xcode and any file that was red I removed the reference.  But that didn't help with restoring the snapshot.

Comment: Did  you find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem tonight.

Comment: No, I haven't solved this yet.  I tried deleting all the unused files as suggested by Thunk, but that didn't work for me.  I even created a brand new project and tried to take a snapshot, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "deleted unused files" did you click Organizer |  Project  | <your project name> | delete button (next to snapshots)? That deletes every snapshot for that project. Your comment about deleting "unused" files makes me wonder if you really cleared all of the the snapshots.

Comment: I didn't delete any snapshot files.  I deleted any project file that showed up in red because xcode lost it's link to the file.

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify that since you said you tried my suggestion. But, my suggestion below is actually to reset the snapshots by deleting all snapshots and starting over. It sucked to lose all my snapshots, but snapshot restore works properly again for me now.

Comment: I'm gonna have to try what you did.  I don't have many snapshots, so losing them won't be an issue for me.  Hopefully that will fix my problem too.

Comment: I deleted all  my snapshots from the Organizer window then I created a new snapshot, but that didn't work.  Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this appears to be caused by deleting files that were no longer needed in the project directory. I was not able to fix the snapshots so that I could restore. I was, however, able to export a full copy from the snapshots via Window | Organizer | Project, selecting the snapshot I wanted, and exporting it to a different directory. That dumped the full contents of my project into the target directory.

After I moved the files I wanted, I then used the organizer's delete button to wipe out all snapshots and start over.

Not a very satisfying outcome, but it did ultimately get me what I needed.